# Auto Detect Required Fields of TFDQuery in Delphi

Tags: database, postgresql, delphi, firedac

I am using, in Delphi XE5, the TFDQuery component to insert and update records from a table in the PostgreSQL database. One drawback I encountered while adding the fields (persisting in DFM) was that it did not detect that some table fields are NOTNULL. The Component should have set the "Required" property of TFields to "True", but what happened was that all fields, including the primary key were set to "False". I would like to know if there is any specific configuration for this, whether it is a component BUG, or if it is an expected behavior.

Comment: I think so, because Unidac Uniquery also uses the same editor and manages to obtain non nullable fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**TFDAutoIncField**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDAutoIncField) doesn't have [**Required**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Required) flag enabled (so even if you enabled [**ExtendedMetadata**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_PostgreSQL_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters) connection parameter, which is what you should do for purpose of persistent field definition, nothing changes). It is expected behavior.

Comment: Actually the autoincrement field does not get the required flag, but reading the documentation based on the link you posted, I could verify that the "ExtendedMetadata" parameter was not active on the connection component (TFDConnection). When activating and creating a new FDQuery, the "required" flag was obtained for the other non-nullable fields. So Thanks